# Expecting string or bytes object

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle, pandas, cx-oracle

I am taking an excel spreadsheet, loading into a Pandas Dataframe then appending the data frame to an Oracle table.

Any potentially sensitive data is starred.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import cx_Oracle
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

#Gets excel file and writes to dataframe
Tk().withdraw()
filename = askopenfilename()
xl = pd.ExcelFile(filename)
print(xl.sheet_names)
ws = input('Type a sheet name to load: \n')
dFrame = xl.parse(ws)

#create engine connection
engine = create_engine('oracle+cx_oracle://*********')
print("Engine created")

with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute("DELETE FROM table")
print("Delete from executed")

#Write dataframe to table
dFrame.to_sql('table',con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
print("Data frame appended to table")
```

However, I get error `TypeError: expecting string or bytes object` (full trace below), I believe this means there is a column in the dataframe which does not match the existing table type.

If that is the case, how can I find which section of the dataframe is causing a problem?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\*****\Documents\CD\Test.py", line 26, in <module>
    dFrame.to_sql('table',con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
  File "C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2130, in to_sql
    dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 450, in to_sql
    chunksize=chunksize, dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\Users\******\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1127, in to_sql
    table.insert(chunksize)
  File "C:\Users\******\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 641, in insert
    self._execute_insert(conn, keys, chunk_iter)
  File "C:\Users\******\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 616, in _execute_insert
    conn.execute(self.insert_statement(), data)
  File "C:\Users\******\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 948, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "C:\Users\******\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 269, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "C:\Users\******\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1060, in _execute_clauseelement
    compiled_sql, distilled_params
  File "C:\Users\******\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1200, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "C:\Users\******\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1416, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\******\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 249, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\******\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1170, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "C:\Users\******\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\oracle\cx_oracle.py", line 969, in do_executemany
    cursor.executemany(statement, parameters)
TypeError: expecting string or bytes object
```

EDIT:

This is the datatypes for each column in pandas and oracle, respectively:

```
Column1 | int64          | NUMBER(10,0)
Column2 | object         | VARCHAR2(128 BYTE)
Column3 | int64          | NUMBER(13,0)
Column4 | object         | VARCHAR2(128 BYTE)
Column5 | object         | VARCHAR2(128 BYTE)
Column6 | float64        | NUMBER(10,0)
Column7 | object         | VARCHAR2(128 BYTE)
Column8 | object         | VARCHAR2(128 BYTE)
Column9 | int64          | NUMBER(5,0)
Column10| datetime64[ns] | DATE
Column11| datetime64[ns] | DATE
Column12| int64          | NUMBER(10,0)
Column13| float64        | NUMBER(10,0)
Column14| object         | VARCHAR2(128 BYTE)
Column15| float64        | NUMBER(10,0)
```

None of those should be causing issues, right?

Comment: If it is coming from Excel you can get any data at all in any cell, so you'll have to check the contents of your data. And yes, it would be nice if more information was given (which row/column caused the problem!). Feel free to create an issue in cx_Oracle requesting that.

Comment: Does Pandas not assign the datatype based on the column contents? Surely it checks the column and assigns a type which will work for all rows in the column? I've added the datatypes for each column from Pandas and Oracle, but can't see where it would go wrong.

Comment: Yes, all of those types should work fine, but does Pandas check *all* rows when assigning a type for the column? Or just a few? How many rows are you processing? Can you check the contents of each column and make sure that all of the rows have the same type?

Comment: So there's only `Column4` which contained both strings and numbers, but Pandas assigns `object` which goes into `VARCHAR2`, so that should be fine. Plus, I'm able to manually insert each row into the table; it's only via Pandas that it fails.
I wondered whether it was a sizing issue as Column5 contained strings which were 300+ characters long, but even after increasing to `VARCHAR2 (500 BYTE)` in Oracle it still doesn't load.

Comment: Pandas is using executemany(), which requires that all of the values be of the same type. If you insert them individually (single row at a time) cx_Oracle adjusts as needed.

Comment: I don't fully understand this. Pandas assigns all the values in a column the same dtype (e.g. `object`). Are you saying that cx_Oracle attempts to assign them a different type afterwards, and does them row by row, resulting in a mismatch of dtypes?

Comment: They clearly aren't all the same type or you wouldn't get the error you are getting! cx_Oracle doesn't change the types itself, but if you insert a row at a time, it will adjust the type of the bind variable to match the type of the incoming value. So if you have this ["1234", 567, "789"] then cx_Oracle will create a string bind variable, then a number bind variable, then a string bind variable again. But with executemany() it will fail.

Answer (score 0):

would you please check if any 'Nan' in your Dataframe? 
Actually I got the same error yesterday, and after add below code in my script, the dataframe has been appended to a oracle table successfully.

```
df = df.fillna('na')
```