# Writing to Oracle: TypeError: expecting string or bytes object

Tags: python, pandas, oracle, sqlalchemy, cx-oracle

I have been breaking my head on this. I am trying to push 65000+ rows with 51 columns to oracle DB but i end up receiving a type error. is there a way i can find out on which column this error is coming from so that i can debug.

Another question  - Can a Datatype "Object" in python dataframe be read a 'Number' Dtype in Oracle?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "c:\users\so-go- activating strategic people capability - deliverable files\ finance\codes-to_use\s1_3_supply_forecasting_input_revamped.py", line 160, in <module>
    hcar.to_sql('HISTORICAL_HCAR', engine, if_exists='append', index=False,schema='HIM_PA_EXTERN_PROD_FIN',dtype=dtyp)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3-2020.11\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2605, in to_sql
    sql.to_sql(

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3-2020.11\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 589, in to_sql
    pandas_sql.to_sql(

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3-2020.11\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1398, in to_sql
    table.insert(chunksize, method=method)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3-2020.11\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 830, in insert
    exec_insert(conn, keys, chunk_iter)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3-2020.11\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 747, in _execute_insert
    conn.execute(self.table.insert(), data)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3-2020.11\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1011, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3-2020.11\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 298, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3-2020.11\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1124, in _execute_clauseelement
    ret = self._execute_context(

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3-2020.11\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1316, in _execute_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3-2020.11\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1514, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_(exc_info[1], with_traceback=exc_info[2])

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3-2020.11\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 182, in raise_
    raise exception

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3-2020.11\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1256, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_executemany(

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3-2020.11\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\oracle\cx_oracle.py", line 1182, in do_executemany
    cursor.executemany(statement, parameters)

TypeError: expecting string or bytes object
```

Comment: Please note that it is *your* responsibility to boil it down from 65K row * 51 columns to say 2 * 2 while getting the same error. Thant post it as a *reproducible example*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, Oracle won't tell you which column is causing the error. So this is a Python / cx_Oracle question, not really an Oracle one. And I assume when you say "dataframe" that you mean a Pandas dataframe, and not PySpark/Dask/Veux/etc.

There's [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42635198/python-typeerror-expecting-string-or-bytes-object) [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51950472/expecting-string-or-bytes-object) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54843611/typeerror-expecting-string-or-bytes-object) about this error with Pandas dataframes. The issue is usually that Pandas dataframe columns have a `dtype`, but *the rows don't all have to match that type* - `object` columns will allow different types in each row.

```
# example - an int, a float, and a str in the same column
pd.DataFrame([12, np.NaN, 'hi'], columns=['ABC'])
```

When you (or sqlalchemy) use `executemany()`, all the rows have to have the same matching set of column types.

[You can check the types in a single column](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/60955/how-to-check-all-values-in-particular-column-has-same-data-type-or-not/60957) by using:

```
df['ABC'].map(type)
```

And so you can check all the columns in a dataframe at once with something like:

```
df.applymap(type).nunique()
```

Which shows the number of types that each column contains. Any column > 1 will probably cause this error. Fix it using `df['ABC'].astype(str)` or `df['ABC'].fillna('')` before sending to Oracle.

Comment: this is exactly what i needed, to know where to start and how to start. Thank you for your detailed information. i was able to find the datatype issue in the python dataframe. issue was 2 different type of datatype in one column